# Why two blocks need to be floated left in order to be aligned?

Tags: html, css

Say I have this HTML:

```
​<div class = "block1">hi</div>
<div class = "block2">hi</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
​.block1 {
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid;
    float: left;
}

​.block2 {
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid;
}
```

Why does block2 need to have `float:left;` in order to be to the right of block1? Isn't the property of block1 (float:left) enough?

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrNYR/)

Comment: You have to clear after floating.

Comment: froznekoi, now it does. Sorry

Comment: where is Fiddle ...no link is there ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`block2` is displayed as a block level element by default, which means it takes up a whole line.

It doesn't necessarily have to have `float:left` to show up on the right of `block1`; if it is displayed as an inline level element through `display:inline`, or `display:inline-block`, it will appear next to its sibling.

http://jsfiddle.net/8GF4B/1/

To explain it in further detail, let us imagine you had set `float:left` on `block2` instead:

```
.block1 {
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid;
}

​.block2 {
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid;
    float: left;
}
```

The first thing that will happen is that block2 will be positioned where it would normally be positioned. Let's find out where.

- block1 is displayed as a block level element
- block level elements are rendered as though they had a line break both before and after the element
- block2 will therefore by default show up on the second line

Now block2 is taken out of the normal flow, and shifted as far left as it can possibly be ... but it is already against the left edge! This results in block2 showing up underneath block1.

Have a look here for a good explanation of the distinction between inline and block-level elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements

Comment: Correct, but that sort of "lateral stacking" behavior only applies to inline elements or floated elements.

Comment: Ok, but when it's a display:block, why do I need to set float:left so the element is to the right of the first block? That attribute doesn't mean "go to the right", does it?

Comment: @HommerSmith Setting float on the first div does not directly affect the layout of the second. When you specify `float:left`, it indicates that this element is to be positioned within the normal flow of the page, then taken out of it and moved as far left as possible (without overlapping).

Answer (score 0):

`<div>` element is a block level element meaning it will be on its seperate line so you require that `float` in your `block2` as it is a `div` element.