# Confusion on float. Why setting width on second element affect floating?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have this HTML:

```
<div class = "block1">hi</div>
<div class = "block2">hi</div>
```

And in one case I have this CSS:

```
.block1 {
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid;
    float: left;
}

.block2 {
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid;
}
```

Which makes this:

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrNYR/1/)

And the second case, I have this CSS:

```
.block1 {
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid;
    float: left;
}

.block2 {
    border:1px solid;
}
```

Which makes this:

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b8QRe/12/)

Why setting a width makes the second div not being side by side with the first div? What if I want the second div to be side by side and have 100px? If I set float:left; it does that, but why?

Comment: Didn't you already asked that earlier ? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209152/why-two-blocks-need-to-be-floated-left-in-order-to-be-aligned#comment17985854_13209152

Comment: Vucko, that is a completely different question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because if you specify a width to your second `div` you need to use `float: left;` for it, because `div` is a block level element, if you don't specify a width, it will take up the rest of space available, if you define a width, it will float besides the other floated div if the space is available, inorder to float it right, you need to use `float: right`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/b8QRe/1/)

Edit: Better understanding...

If you do not define width

```
------------------------------------------
               total space                     Legend (/ - empty space)

------------- Example 1 ----------------
div1(floated left) ///////////////////////
                   ^---------------------^
                     This space will be taken 
                by the div which is without width
------------- Example 2 ----------------
div1(floated left)
div2(same size as 1 wont float unless you give float: left;)

 ------------- Example 3 ----------------
 div1(floated left) div2(besides div 1 if widths are different without giving float left)
------------------------------------------
```

As you said if you specify width it should float to left, it ont as you are giving same width to the `div2` what you gave to `div1` [Reference](http://w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting), so if you change say `150px` for second div it will work... [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b8QRe/13/)

But if you clear your floats before floating the second div it wont make the div float besides the other 1, See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/b8QRe/2/)

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester dude just wait for the complete answer

Comment: Too bad no one can see it now, but your answer has transformed quite a lot since its original version...

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester this is how stackoverflow works, post the important point first, later enhance the quality of your answer

Comment: I know that, I do that too often, but your original answer was quite unsufficient and totally unrecognisable in what you have now. Never mind. You go from -1 to +1.

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester agreed but I made it better :)

Comment: I still don't understand this. Why when I don't specify a width, goes side by side? And if I set a width, it doesn't go to the side of the first block?

Comment: You didn't read my answer correctly, i said if you don't specify the width it will take up the rest of the space

Comment: I did read that. How is "taking the rest of space" related to go side by side? My confusion is that I don't understand why when not setting the width it goes to the right of the first block, while when setting the width it goes down.

Comment: this is indetail article on floats, just give a read http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: I will give it a read, but I would like you to clarify that. How not setting the width makes the second block to be on the right of the first block, whereas setting a width makes it go under? I have edited my answer with Jsfiddles...

Comment: Mr.Alien thanks for the edit. I just have a question. Why if the width if different it floats, but if the width is the same it doesn't?? I have never heard of that.

Comment: @HommerSmith that's what I gave you the reference link for :) and you welcome

Answer (score 0):

**Float** is a CSS positioning property.

In first block you have define float left but not closing floating off. for that you need to use `clear:both;`

see your updated results:

[DifferenceBetweenFloatLeftAndRight](http://jsfiddle.net/b8QRe/10/)

[jsFiddleWithClearingFloat](http://jsfiddle.net/MrNYR/2/)